# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a002b (com.sapplication:id/content) for fragment ManagemntPageFragment

Tags: android, fragment

i want to redirect activity to fragment when clicking button but it gives me error.

here is my activity class

```
public class EventDetailsNotif extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eventdetails);
        ImageButton imgmenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgmenu);
        imgmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadFragmentObj = new LoadFragment(getFragmentManager());
                loadFragmentObj.initializeFragment(new ManagemntPageFragment());


            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my load fragment class is here.

```
public class LoadFragment {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager1;

    public LoadFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager2) {
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager2;
    }

    public void initializeFragment(Fragment resultFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, resultFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

and my content.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and my fragment class.

```
public class ManagemntPageFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView footervie;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.managmntpg,
            container, false);

    footervie = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.footervie);

    advtimagepath = Utility.getSharedKey("advertiseFooter_image",
            getActivity());

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(advtimagepath)) {
        if (advtimagepath.endsWith(".jpeg")
                || advtimagepath.endsWith(".jpg")
                || advtimagepath.endsWith(".gif")
                || advtimagepath.endsWith(".png")) {
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(advtimagepath, footervie);

        } else {

        }
    }
return view ;
}
}
```

please reply if have solution

Comment: In onCreate() you called setContentView(R.layout.eventdetails). But when your xml file is called content.xml, you should call setContentView(R.layout.content). Or you should include the FrameLayout (id:content) in your eventdetails.xml.

Comment: post your **ManagemntPageFragment** class

Comment: solved issue with changing layout on button click

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you have below code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

in eventdetails layout file because you set content menu in activity to this layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.eventdetails);
```

and if you don't use support library for fragment you will have compatibility with older android version!